# Django: alternatives to count()

Tags: python, mysql, django, pagination

I have a Django app that displays paginated search results. Each page displays 20 results and I have a pagination bar at the bottom that displays the 5 pages less than and 5 pages greater than the current page (like Google). The problem is, for the pagination bar I call count() to get the total number of results so I know if there is actually 5 pages of results ahead of the current page.

The problem is more general queries could take around 10 seconds to perform a `count()` on. I don't actually care about the exact number, since most of my users will probably never reach the end of the results. Is there any way to estimate the output of count, or more generally, estimate the number of returned results from a query?

This is currently my query to get the actual results.

```
results = Item.objects.filter(title__icontains=query).order_by('views')[offset:limit]
```

The `offset` and `limit` variables refer to the segment of results that is shown on the current page. The only way I can see to solve my problem is to get the result segment of ~5 pages ahead and check whether it's empty. However, there are a lot of the edge cases for that solution, and I really don't want to spend a day coding that if there is an easier solution.

Comment: You could use EXPLAIN it returns a estimate how many rows that the qeury needs to check..

Comment: @Raymond Nijland Could you provide an example? Is there a way to use EXPLAIN through django, or would I have to write my own raw sql?

Answer (score 0):

Also not ideal solution but might be worth testing for your particular situation. You might introduce a timeout for function making the query with the help of:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576780/

... or similar solution. You either need exact number of rows or the information that there's going to be a lot. That requires a bit of benchmarking to get a timoeout right and is still vulnerable to some externalities but might as well just work fine in 99.9% of cases.

Also it reduces the long queries load on the db.